# Android: empty ListView after Button Back pressed

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have an activity, which shows different fragments. The layout of the fragments is usually a listView. When you click an item in the listView, the next fragment will be shown. The fragments have a SwipeRefreshLayout.

The problem is when the button back is pressed, the listView is sometimes empty.
In debug i can see that the data is still where, but the listView does not repaint it always. In the case the listView is empty, also the refreshing of the listView don´t work. The data reloads, but it is not visible.

I have an adapter and i call notifyDataSetChanged. I have also tried to reset the list and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged, but it doesn´t work.

onCreate() of the fragment:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // creates the adapter for the different fragments
     adapter = createListViewAdapter();
     setListAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

onViewCreated() of the fragment:

```
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
      // reload data when it is not present
      this.values = values;
      this.filteredValues = values;
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      this.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
        // reload data
        this.values = values;
        this.filteredValues = values;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      )};
      super.onViewCreate(view, savedInstanceState);
     }
```

the adapter:

```
    public abstract class BaseListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

       @Override
       public int getCount(){ 
         return filteredValues.size();
       }

       @Override
       public T getItme(int position){
         return filteredValues.get(positon);
       }

       @Override
       public long getItemI(int position){
        return 0;
       }

       @Override
       public Filter getFilter(){
         return BaseListViewFragment.this.getFilter();
       }
     }
```

`getView()`, `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType` are implemented in the different fragments.

The problem occurs not regular, any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Removing the SwipeRefreshLayout fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called

```
@Override
protected void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isUserVisible){
}
```

just override that method and check is the fragment is visible to user and make neccary action like notifyDatasetChanged().

nulll check is important.

Thanks

Comment: Overriding setUserVisibleHint did not change something. ListView is still sometimes empty.

Comment: fragment inside a fragment?

Comment: No, i have one actitivty with one fragment, on a click on an item i change the fragment. The fragments are in a stack, so i can navigate back.

Comment: Make sure every time your oncreateView() and onViewCreated callled

Can you please share the full code